# Show 5 posts and than 3 posts offset with pagination

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, query-posts

I am trying to get the first 5 posts displayed with different styles, and then the next 3 with different styles. They need to have working pagination as well.

On my readings setting I have set the number of posts to show to 6.

I managed to do it with query_posts, but I don't know if it's the right way.

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <div class="posts-wrap">
            <div class="grid">

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format());
                    ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $page_num = $paged;

    if ($page_num === 0) :
        $page_num = $page_num + 3;
        query_posts('showposts=3&offset=5&paged=' . $page_num);
    else :
        query_posts('showposts=3&paged=' . $page_num);
    endif;

    ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <div class="more">
        <div class="all-by-date">
            <h2>Browse Archives</h2>
            <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives(['type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12]); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="posts-wrap">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'single-preview');
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $page_num = $paged; ?>
    <?php query_posts('offset=8&paged=' . $paged); ?>
    <?php numbered_pagination_links(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am wondering if there's a better way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under **settings - reading**, set 'blog pages show at most' to 8

then use conditional statements based on the current post number in the loop;

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
//conditionally outputting the opening tags for the first section
if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) { ?>
        <div class="posts-wrap">
            <div class="grid">
<?php } 
//conditionally outputting the template part                    
                    if( $wp_query->current_post <= 4 ) get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format());

//conditionally outputting the closing tags
if( $wp_query->current_post == 4 || $wp_query->current_post < 4 && $wp_query->current_post == $wp_query->post_count-1 ) { ?>

            </div>
        </div>
<?php } 

//conditionally outputting the opening tags for the second section
if( $wp_query->current_post == 5 ) { ?>
    <div class="more">
        <div class="all-by-date">
            <h2>Browse Archives</h2>
            <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12)); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="posts-wrap">
<?php }                 
//conditionally outputting the template part
                    if( $wp_query->current_post > 4 ) get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'single-preview');
                    ?>
<?php //conditionally outputting the closing tags
if( $wp_query->current_post == 7 || $wp_query->current_post > 4 && $wp_query->current_post == $wp_query->post_count-1 ) { ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>      
                <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php numbered_pagination_links(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

it might look more complicated, but you don't need to worry about the pagination.
the code will need to be adapted if you want to show the archive links even if there are no more posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I forgot to mention, the blog pages show at most must equal 6 since I use it in another post archive page. My guess is that I have to use 'pre_get_posts'?

Comment: yes, 'pre_get_posts' is the way to go...